# lt Spice simulation duplication error

Tags: simulation, ltspice, error

I am new to using LT Spice. I have imported an operational amplifier. When I try to run a simulations response  I received an error (shown in the screenshot.)
[image]

It says Netlist  Error: Duplicated Instance Name, "1" in C/.../finalsimulation.asc the location where the file is.

After this I proceed to have another error Trouble generating Netlist spice.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be the problem and how i could fix this error. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the names of the capacitors to the right of U1 and U2? Did you write "1" as a name where you should've written "1" as a value?

Comment: Yes i accidently wrote the names as 1 instead having a value of 1 Farad

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore the fact that your schematic makes absolutely no sense as a functional circuit, you:

- Named two capacitors "1" which spice would have no idea what to do with, as these are both named the same and are not capacitors anymore.
- Set the values of two resistors to "R" which either you know what you are doing and this is part of a parameter sweep, or you don't and Spice would have no idea what to do with.
- Have op-amps with shorted power rails.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for the response. I have made these changes.It still doesn't seem to run.
Also please would mind explaining what makes you think that this doesn't make sense as a functional circuit ?

Comment: @Muzzammmilmia the opamps with shorted power rails and power supplies at their inputs and capacitors being used in a fully-DC circuit should give you a clue.